# Livewire session returns NULL in Laravel Auth Middleware

Tags: laravel, session, jwt

I have a livewire component that needs to send requests using JWT.

As the livewire `GET` request is not sending the token by default, I decided to modify the Laravel's Authentication middleware in order to send the token that I put in session in the livewire component, via bearer in Laravel Auth middleware.

That the variable that I added to the session in my livewire component, returns NULL when I try to retrieve it in the Authentication middleware.

1.Livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public function mount(TransactionCheckoutRequest $request)
    {
        session(['x__livewire__token' => 'put token in session' ]);
    }
}
```

2.Laravel auth middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        # Check if request is made using LIVEWIRE
        if ( request()->hasHeader('x-livewire') ) {

            /**
             * get token from session
             *
             * 
             * But, this $token return NULL
             * instead token value.
             */
            $token = session()->get('x__livewire__token');

            $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
            $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            // # Send token to request header
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);
        }

        # After that, authenticate livewire request
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        return $next($request);
    }


    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if ( !$request->expectsJson() ) {
            return route('user.login');
        }
    }
}
```

3.Web route file

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
        
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'jwt.verifyer', 'hostname.access.verifyer']], function() {
        
        # Here is LIVEWIRE component
        Route::get('/processing', HelloWorld::class)->name('transaction.checkout');
    });

});
```

Can somebody explain how should I extend the middleware to use the token?

Comment: Can you please include your code instead of screenshots?

Comment: Stackoverflow prevents me from adding images. That's why I added the link to the images only.

Comment: I meant to include the source code in text format instead of links to the images or images overall.

Comment: It's done. I've just included the source codes

Answer (score 0):

Livewire uses its own request when making requests. if you want to send additional data. You can send it using addHeaders.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("livewire:load", function(event) {
        Livewire.addHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {{ $token }}',
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.